# How to tuning Elasticsearch performance with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We are using ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana for analyzing nginx logs.
Now we have about 10 nginx servers with logstash-forwarder, 1 logstash server (8 cores, 8G), 2 ElasticSearch nodes (each one is 4 cores and 8G) both with SSD hard driver.

Our problem is that the ElasticSearch cluster's indexing performance is not good enough. The speed of the nginx log generation is faster than indexing. And we don't think the logstash server and Elastic cluster is doing their best. Because the performance are not full.

Logstash server(8 cores) using CPU heavily. Load average is about 3-6.
Following is one of the Elasticsearch's top data.

```
top - 14:26:08 up 1 day, 32 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.69, 0.75, 0.77
Tasks: 115 total,   1 running, 114 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 14.2%us,  1.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 69.9%id, 14.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.1%st
```

Using BigDesk plugin for monitoring the Elasticsearch indexing figure. The value is at round 2K/s.  %wa is not always high like upper.

Following is one of the Elasticsearch's iostat data.

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
       9.99    0.00    2.66   12.10    0.15   75.10

Device:           rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
vda               11.60     4.80   18.60    0.80     0.12     0.02    14.93     0.01    0.60   0.56   1.08
vdb               4.40 21633.80  190.80  158.40    11.02    71.63   484.73    42.52  105.02   1.19  41.42
```

I disabled replicas, disabled _all fields.
Network is good.

How can we tuning the performance accordingly. I heard someone could make the performance better to 20K/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add more Logstash 1.5 instances could increase the performance. The bottleneck is not the Elastic Search, is Logstash. But the Logstash's performance is not good enough.

Finally I used a kafka as a event cache, and pushed log event to ES using my own codes. And the machnes of the ES servers could be used fully.

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the filters from logstash and just add metrics to see how much your cluster can scale.

Starting with a single ES node and edit settings for ES from here : http://edgeofsanity.net/article/2012/12/26/elasticsearch-for-logging.html

the metrics plugin : http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/filters/metrics